# node-sqlite3 database connection indicating database opened when sqlite is not even installed

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

```
var sqlite_connection = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  new sqlite3.Database("edupages", function(err){
    if(err){reject(err)}
      else{resolve()}
  })
})

  sqlite_connection.then(
    function(){console.log('Connected to the sqlite database')},
    function(err){console.log(err)}
    )
```

console shows "Connected to the sqlite database", when codeis executed.

From node-sqlite3 docs:

> > new sqlite3.Database(filename, [mode], [callback])
>
> callback (optional): If provided, this function will be called when
>   the database was opened successfully or when an error occurred. The
>   first argument is an error object. When it is null, opening succeeded.
>   If no callback is provided and an error occurred, an 'error' event
>   with the error object as the only parameter will be emitted on the
>   database object. If opening succeeded, an 'open' event with no
>   parameters is emitted, regardless of whether a callback was provided
>   or not.

Will I have to add an event listener for the open event? Instead of just checking the callback's first parameter's values (i.e. null: meaning database opened, or error: meaning an error occurred)

If so, is it inherently bad design on part of the authors of the library? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: "when sqlite is not even installed" -> sqlite does not need to be installed. `npm install sqlite3` should be enough. Is there any indication its not working?

Comment: I found a file named edupages generated by sqlite3. The premise of my question was wrong. Guess that closes the issue.